# How to properly quote spaces when building a string of options in Ash / Bash?

Tags: bash, sh, ash

```
livy@linux:~$ qemu_options="-enable-kvm -name \"Virtual Machine 1\"";
livy@linux:~$ qemu_options="$qemu_options -cpu host -smp cores=4 -m 2G";
livy@linux:~$ echo "$qemu_options";
-enable-kvm -name "Virtual Machine 1" -cpu host -smp cores=4 -m 2G
livy@linux:~$ qemu-system-x86_64 $qemu_options;
qemu-system-x86_64: Machine: Could not open 'Machine': No such file or directory
```

I already tried and successfully preserved the quotes around *Virtual Machine 1* string. Why does it not work? And how to quote it properly?

Comment: Use bash arrays.

Comment: @KamilCuk Despite the fact that my shell is Bash, I always try to write ash compatible code to make it portable. No array is available in ash, however.

Comment: Use positional parameters then. Like `set -- -enable-kvm -name ...; qemu-system-x86_64 "$@"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does it not work?

Because word splitting is performed after quotes are recognized on unquoted results of other expansions. The content of expansions is not scanned, only splitted.

> how to quote it properly?

Use bash arrays.

If not, use a function.

If you have exhausted any other alternatives, enter the dark side with `eval` and properly double-quote arguments and re-evaluate them upon call. Remember that `eval` is one letter away from evil.

```
qemu_options="$(printf " %q" -enable-kvm -name "Virtual Machine 1")"
qemu_options+="$(printf " %q" -cpu host -smp cores=4 -m 2G")"
eval qemu-system-x86_64 "$qemu_options"
```